# Catchable fatal error: Object of class User could not be converted to string in

Tags: php, function

i have problem could not be converted to string...

**Catchable fatal error: Object of class User could not be converted to string in /home/mysite/example.com/directory/lang/lang.english.php on line 74**

but i think error in userclass.php:

```
class User {
  var $userid;
  var $username;
  var $pwd;
  var $emailaddr;
  var $icon;
  var $usertype;
  var $lang;
  var $createdate;
  var $loggedIn;
  var $dflths;
  var $dfltas;
  var $auto;

  function User() {
    $this->userid = "";
    $this->username = "";
    $this->pwd = "";
    $this->emailaddr = "";
    $this->icon = "";
    $this->usertype = "0";
    $this->createdate = "";
    $this->lang = "english";
    $this->loggedIn = FALSE;
    $this->dflths = 0;
    $this->dfltas = 0;
    $this->auto = "N";
  }
}
```

Comment: If you add a __toString() magic method to your class, then you can `echo` a class instance; otherwise you will get this error when you try to echo the class instance

Comment: Note that this class has been written for PHP4, are you still using an ancient version of PHP, or are you using PHP5 now?

Comment: Thanks but please do you edit on my code?

Comment: "but i think error in userclass.php" and why is that exactly?

Comment: my PHP Version 5.2.17

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something is attempting to convert your User to a string, but it doesn't have a `__toString`.

This may be what you want to add to your user class:

```
public function __toString() {
    return $this->username;
}
```

Also your constructor should be called `__construct` not `User` and you should not use the `var` keyword. Those things come from really old (something like 15 years ago) versions of PHP.

I would recommended replacing `var` with `protected` if you use getters and setters. If not, then use `public` to avoid breaking other code.

Comment: tried but: Catchable fatal error: Method User::__toString() must return a string value in

Comment: @BZC You'll get that error if `$this->username` is not a string. It should be if that constructor has executed. Did you rename it to `__construct`? If username can be `null` or something else that is not a string then you'll need to convert it to a string. You could try `return strval( $this->username );` and see what happens.